# Migrating jQuery selector to angularjs for third party vendor client help functionality

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to *migrate* old jQuery code to angularjs.

The issue that I'm having is that I'm not sure on the best approach. 
Bascially, depending on the selector a different type of 'event' needs to be pushed into a array called *gt*.

The purpose of the jQuery code is to provide detailed info of clients having issues while filling in a form. the gt array is picked up by third party software that helps the clients by asking if they want to chat.

Example of how the array is populated:

```
        $('a').live('click', { element: this }, function (element) {

            _clickedElement = this;
            var linkUrl = element.currentTarget.hostname + element.currentTarget.pathname;
            var querystring = window.location.search
            var shortLocationUrl = window.location.href.replace(querystring, "").replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "");

            if (element.currentTarget.hostname.length > 0 && element.currentTarget.target != "_blank" && linkUrl != shortLocationUrl) { //click on a link that opens in the current window and points to a page external to this part
                _gt.push(['event', { eventName: 'Leave_Page_' + chat.name, name: chat.name, pageName: chat.pageName, locale: _locale, isClient: chat.isClient }]);
                _pushLeavePageEvent = false;
            }
            else if (this.id == backButtonId) { //click "previous"
                _gt.push(['event', { eventName: 'Go_Back_' + chat.name, name: chat.name, pageName: chat.pageName, locale: _locale, isClient: chat.isClient }]);
                _pushLeavePageEvent = false;
            }

            return true;
        });
```

So for all the a tags inside my page (or form) the above code needs to be executed.
What would be a good approach to have similar behaviour in Angularjs?

I was thinking of a directive but I'm not sure whether to make this a directive at the level of my form or make a directive that I then use throughout my page?

P.S.: similar behaviour is needed (pushing an event into the gt array) for all the input, textarea and select fields on the page as well as the errors on the page caused by the clients and when a client hovers over a tooltip.

Comment: Using a directive is definitely a sensible way forward. Depending on where you want your event array to be accessible you could create a `service` to store and manipulate this data.

Comment: I'll add more detailed info on why this is needed cause it's a bit vague now I suppose.